# Extracting string from label, can't find Object in Squish

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, squish

Im trying to read a widget displaying a string containing coordinates. The goal is to extract the coordinates as a String but Squish can't find the object in the Objekt Map, only using Pick tool can I find the object.
Meaning during run the script fails when I try to read the string.

The following is part of a larger script. The window is called System Display and contains a button called properies. Properties is itself a window with a unique id and contains among other things, the coordinates.

Javascript:

```
clickButton(waitForObjectItem(":System Display.Properties_JButton"));
var Coord = waitForObjectExist(":Display Properties [ID 001]_JFormattedTextField").value;
```

Right now the get the error message

```
Object: Display Properties [ID 001] _JFormattedTextField' not fund. Object name not found in ObjectMap
```

Comment: You are using a Squish symbolic name, as can be seen by the colon in the first character of the object name that you are trying to use. Symbolic names are only (!) placeholders for "real names", which are sets of property names and property value pairs. Where did you get that symbolic name from? Did you make it up yourself? (There are typos in the error message provided by you. Try to be exact, as it increases chances and speeds up getting help.)

Comment: Used the pick tool to extract the symbolic name. However I also tried using the real name and recived the same error. Done some more testing and it looks like the object dosen't apperar in the object map until you use the picking tool. However since I can't use pick tool since Im trying to automate the process, I have to somehow open an object thats not in the object map.

Comment: Nevermind, manage do solve it. Somewhat long and odd solution so won't type all of it here but the key idea where to right click on the object and remove the propertiy that keept changing between tests.

Comment: Another option can be to use the regular expression and wildcard property value matching functionality of Squish. Picking an object does not add a name for it to the object map. For that interact with it while recording, or pick it and then choose Copy Symbolic/Real Name in the context menu of the object's node in the Application Objects view.

Comment: As for looking up an object that is not in the object map, simply use a suitable object name for it, for example {"type": "QPushButton", "caption": "OK"}.

Comment: The widlcard option never appeared for me, I couldn't change the state from equal to wildcard for some reason. Also the problem with "describing" the object was that the only "uniqe" property between iterations were some piece of text that included a random number.

Comment: Without knowing what you tried exactly it is not possible to say what went wrong. When using the text based object map, edit it in a text editor and use ?= instead of = to enable wildcard matching. When using the script based object map use (Python example) {"type": "QPushButton", "caption": Wildcard("OK*")} to enable wildcard matching.